# Oracle APEX: ¿Cómo consultar dinamicamente a una base de datos teniendo un solo informe interactivo?

Tags: javascript, express, oracle-11g, plsql, apex

tengo una región (informe interactivo) y Tengo un elemento (lista de selección), necesito hacer que la región se refresque automaticamente y me muestre un query dependiendo el valor que se escoja en la lista de selección. He intentado hacerlo con acción dinámica mediante PL, pero siento que aún no tengo la idea clara. Les agradecería mucho alguna sugerencia.

Uso apex 18 y oracle 11g.

Comment: Podrías compartir lo que tienes hecho hasta ahora?

Comment: Haz una pagina con una `región html` ahi agregas la `lista de selección` con un botón `submit`. Luego haces otra pagina con el `reporte interactivo` y le pones un query cualquiera. Luego en la pagina html haces que el submit de la pagina te mande a la pagina del `reporte interactivo` y en los `branch` le pasas a la nueva pagina el valor seleccionado de la `lista de selección`. Por ultimo editas el query del reporte y pones el query correcto y donde necesites el valor de la `lista de selección` pones el nombre que pusiste en el `branch`.`:PNO_NOMBRE`. No conozco otra forma.

Answer (score 2):

ayer me dediqué a analizar la situación e intente hacerlo con una función.
El primer paso fue crear object Type en un paquete llamado pck_tipos, que a continuacion dejo:

```
 type fcomun is record( 
 cat_activo varchar(255),
 descripcion varchar2(255),
 ubicacion varchar2(255),
 clave_empleado number,
 propiedad varchar2(255));
 type t_fcomun is table of fcomun;
```

Luego, en un paquete llamado pck_activos cree la función siguiente:

```
function f_categoria(pvi_cat in varchar2)
    return pck_tipos.t_fcomun
    pipelined is
begin  
    for ptr in (select cat_activo, descripcion, ubicacion, clave_empleado, propiedad 
      from maestro_activo 
      where cat_activo = pvi_cat) loop      
declare
        rec pck_tipos.fcomun;
begin
        rec.cat_activo  := ptr.cat_activo;
        rec.descripcion := ptr.descripcion;
        rec.ubicacion  := ptr.ubicacion;
        rec.clave_empleado := ptr.clave_empleado;
        rec.propiedad  := ptr.propiedad;
        pipe row(rec);
      end;
    end loop;
  end;
```

En el encabezado del mismo paquete va lo siguiente:

```
function f_categoria(pvi_cat in varchar2)       
return pck_tipos.t_fcomun
    pipelined;
```

En el apex, en la región creada se manda a llamar la función con el query siguiente y tomando en cuenta el elemento P10_CAT que es de tipo lista de selección y es donde se manda a llamar el LOV de las categorías:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego se procede a crear una acción dinamica en el elemento P10_CAT:

```
Evento: Cambiar
Tipo de selección: Elementos
Elementos: P10_CAT
```

Crear acción verdadera:

```
Acción: Ejecutar página
Disparar al inicializar: No
```

Espero sea de ayuda un poco, realmente me falta mucho por aprender pero me encanta el mundo de PL y me siento especialmente cómodo con application express.

Answer (score 0):

A continuación los pasos generales que debes seguir:

1. En el Informe Interáctivo, incluir en la consulta SQL el elemento LOV.
   Agregar también elemento en Page Items to Submit.
2. Crear una Acción Dinámica que se ejecute cuando cambie el valor del elemento.
   Acción: Refresh
   Tipo de selección: Región
   Región: Informe Interáctivo.

De esta manera, cuando el usuario final seleccione un valor en la Lista de Valores, solo el Informe se refrescará, no toda la página.